# Cyber Security Training v. Cyber Security Education for Middle to High Schoolers

Tags: professional-education

In my community, we have one state university that offers cyber security training once a year to high school students that show interest.  Last year a student, after receiving this training, hacked his school.

Should we be training high school students or focus more on education?  Do you feel that a "all of the above" approach will help mitigate risk associated with training minors in cyber security, and if not, what training would you provide to the students if you think it would be a good idea to train them in the first place?

Comment: Aren't training and education the same thing? Or do you mean focusing on standard curriculum?

Comment: To me, training is hands on situations such as CTF's (capture the flags) where TTP (tactics, techniques and  procedures) are taught, where education is more along the lines of increasing awareness and controlling one's digital footprint through good practices in online behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a big concern in the industry that there are not enough people to fill InfoSec employment needs and there is a push to try and attract students into these roles. So, when you say "should" there is a scope issue.

We, as an industry, need the kids who are interested to have their appetites "whet". Yes, there is a risk that they might use their knowledge for ill, but then they could also learn the same skills via YouTube. At least by having professionals doing the teaching, we can also pass on values and ethics (the "would you rather them learn this stuff on the street?" argument).

General Education is important to all students universally, but Tactics Training also has a place for those who are interested so that those kids can be guided to use that interest for good.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I see your argument as similar to the argument for requiring a concealed permit to carry a concealed firearm currently being debated in my state.  If a criminal wants to carry out a crime, they will.

Comment: The particular issue with "hacking" is that the Tactics Training is so readily available without context or guidance.